# Git: if I want to store old versions of my software - only choice is to create a branch?

Tags: git, github

If I want a permanent older version of a software package to exist, say on Github, is the only option to create a new branch and never merge back with the original branch? Or is there a better way?

Comment: That's what tags are for. http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [GitHub’s documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-releases/), you should use tags for that.